# Calculate depth of unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, list, html-lists

How can I get the depth of the *deepest* `li` tag in an unordered list?

For instance, this unordered list deepest `li` has depth equal with `3`:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li></li> <!-- I am the deepest -->
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supposing you don't have a selector (id, class etc), you need a simple loop in the elements that *don't have `ul`*.

```
// create maxDepth and cDepth variables
var maxDepth = -1
  , cDepth   = -1
  ;

// each `li` that hasn't `ul` children
$("li:not(:has(ul))").each(function() {

    // get the current `li` depth
    cDepth = $(this).parents("ul").length;

    // it's greater than maxDepth found yet
    if (cDepth > maxDepth) {

       // this will become the max one
       maxDepth = cDepth;
    }
});

// alert
alert(maxDepth);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hjR6E/3/)

If you have `.myClass` selector for the deepest `li`:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li class="myClass"></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

it's very simple: just count its `ul` parents

```
var depth = $(".myClass").parents("ul").length;
```

Comment: The example in jsfiddle works. i can't put a class on the deepest since it will be a dynamically created list. Thanks!

Comment: @RascalCapac You're welcome. I added the second version to be sure you know it. If you don't know which element is the deepest, only a loop will do that for you. :-)

Comment: @RascalCapac :-) I am happy to help users here, on StackOverflow. Best regards from Romania. :-)

Comment: it's not simple as you say. can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @C-link I added inline comments. I guessed it's simple enough. :-)

Comment: I wasn't understanding this $(this).parents("ul").length thanks.

Comment: @C-link It counts how many `ul` parents the current `li` has, that is actually the *depth* of that `li`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
var parent = $('ul').children(),
child = parent;

while (child.length) {
parent = child;
child = child.children();
}

alert(parent.html());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xN6d5/61/)

**Html**

```
<ul >
<li></li>
<li>
  <ul>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li> I am the deepest </li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```